# Shorten Decimal Places of ModelForm field Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-forms

I have a decimal field that goes to the 4th place which I want to render in my template to the 2nd place (I need it to the 4th for other calculations). I've tried using a template float filter to get shorten the decimal places but the result is the entire field disappears.

**The field in my model is:**

```
price_retail = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=9, decimal_places=4)
```

**My form is:**

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['price_retail']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.fields['price_retail'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'input-price'

ProductFormSet = modelformset_factory(Product, form=ProductForm, extra=0)
```

**Template with FloatFilter (field doesn't display at all)**

```
<td>{{form.price_retail|floatformat:2}}</td>
```

**Template without FloatFilter (field displays but to the 4th decimal)**

I apprecaite the feedback and expertise.

```
<td>{{form.price_retail}}</td>
```

Comment: Is this for editing existing values, or creating new ones?  If it's for editing new ones, what do you want to happen to existing values with more than two decimal places?

Comment: It's for editing. When edited from the form I can change any values of the 3rd and 4th place to 0's (or just drop them). I just need it to the 2nd decimal when edited from the form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`floatformat` expects its argument to be something it can convert to a `Decimal` instance, not a form field.  `form.price_retail` is a form field instance (a `DecimalField`, to be specific).

`DecimalField` does accept a [`decimal_places`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DecimalField.decimal_places) argument, but that's for input validation rather than rounding of existing values.

I think you'll need to either [`quantize`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize) the value yourself - probably in the form's `__init__` method, or possibly in a subclassed field type or even a custom widget - or render the input element yourself so you can use `floatformat` directly on the HTML `input`'s `value` attribute.  I think the simplest way is to do it in the `__init__`, something like this:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Meta as above
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'instance' in kwargs:
            kwargs['instance'].price_retail = kwargs['instance'].price_retail.quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.fields['price_retail'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'input-price'
        self.fields['price_retail'].decimal_places = 2
```

You can of course use whatever rounding strategy you like, as documented for quantize.

I *think* this will not actually change the `price_retail` value if you submit the form without editing it, because the field will appear not to have changed from its initial value.  But I haven't tested that.

Comment: Worked perfect! I really appreciate your time and feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the decimal places on the actual form field:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
    self.fields['price_retail'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'input-price'
    self.fields['price_retail'].decimal_places = 2
```

Comment: That argument only affects validation, not display of the initial value.  It's sufficient for creating new instances but not for editing.